# How to join txt files with file name and only last line of txt file

Tags: batch

I have a directory with 50 txt files in it. I need a batch to merge the last line of each file into one txt file.
I also need the name of each file merged on the same line with the data merged.

I am able to merge all the files into one with the file name on each line now, but I only want the last line in each file and not all.
Below is what i am currently using.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Creating %1...
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\User01\Documents\temp"

FOR /F "Delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
ECHO Adding %%G
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%sourcedir%\%%~G") do (
Echo %%a, %%G >> Status.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

- You either need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) or a sub routine to read file contents into a var and only print the last line.
- Your batch states to create `%1` but you use `Status.csv` instead.
- your batch (fragment) is missing some closing parentheses.

---

```
@ECHO OFF & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1"=="" (Echo no output file provided & pause & exit /B 1)
ECHO Creating %1...
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\User01\Documents\temp"
( Echo File,Lastline
    For /f "Delims=" %%G IN ('DIR /B /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt"') DO (
      For /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in ("%sourcedir%\%%~G") do Set "Line=%%a"
      Echo %%G,!Line!
    )
) > "%~1"
```